# Delete only fully formed line ranges from a text file while ignoring those that only have a start delimiter

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I what to delete lines between START and END keywords as described below:

```
START
text1
text2
text3
START
text4
END
text5
text6
START
test7
START
test8
END
```

My problem is in the START keyword not always closed with END. As from the example above the first START did not close with END but another START again after TEXT3.

So I cannot use the following sed command:

```
sed '/START/,/END/d' test.txt
```

because it will delete the lines from TEXT1 to TEXT 4 and also TEXT7-8.

But I want only to delete lines TEXT4 and TEXT8. So the following output should be like this:

```
START
text1
text2
text3
text5
text6
START
text7
```

Comment: @kaylum No, it's different.

Comment: @mklement0 Thank you for editing the title to make it clear. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

becomes easier by reversing the file linewise:

```
$ tac test.txt | sed '/END/,/START/d' | tac
START
text1
text2
text3
text5
text6
START
test7
```

Answer (score 2):

In awk:

```
$ cat foo.awk
/START/ { printf "%s", b; b="" }                       # at START output buffer and empty it
{ b=b $0 ORS }                                         # gather buffer
/END/ { b="" }                                         # at empty buffer at END also
END { printf "%s", b }                                 # Thanks @mklement0, this is needed
```

Run it:

```
$ awk -f foo.awk foo
START
text1
text2
text3
text5
text6
START
test7
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for updating (and correcting my correction :); perhaps also mention that your `awk` solution has the added advantage of being POSIX-compliant (unlike mine).

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a *GNU* `awk` solution that may be of interest for the advanced GNU-specific features used.
Otherwise:

- If performance is not a concern (multiple child processes, file being read multiple times), use [Sundeep's ingeniously simple `sed` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40296776/45375)
- Otherwise, use [James Brown's elegant, POSIX-compliant `awk` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40299389/45375).

---

If you have *GNU* `awk`, you can try the following:

```
awk -v RS='(^|\n)START|END(\n|$)' '
  RT ~ "END" {
    skipped=1
    next
  }
  NF {
    print (skipped ? "" : "START\n") gensub("^\n+|\n+$", "", "g")
    skipped=0
  }
' test.txt
```

- `-v RS='(^|\n)START|END(\n|$)'` breaks the input into (multiline) records by the words `START` or `END` appearing (by themselves) on a line.

  - This is a GNU extension in the sense that POSIX supports only literal, single-character values for `RS`, the input record separator.
- `RT ~ "END"` looks for substring `END` in `RT`, the record terminator (using regex matching).

  - `RT` is a GNU-specific variable that contains the actual record terminator found at the end of the current input record. This enables to tell whether the record at hand ended in `START` or `END`
  - If `RT` contains `END`, we know that we're inside a fully formed range, set a flag to indicate we're skipping this record, and perform the skip by executing `next`.
- Pattern `NF` is short for `NF > 0` and ensures that the associated block is only executed if the record at hand is nonempty (based on the `RS` value, the very first input record will be empty; note however, that this would also eliminate adjacent `START` lines).

  - `print (skipped ? "" : "START\n") gensub("^\n+|\n+$", "", "g")` outputs the current record:

    - `(skipped ? "" : "START\n")` precedes the output with `START` only if the previous record *wasn't* a fully formed range. If it was, then it was essentially just cut out of the input and no new range starts. (Caveat: if the input doesn't *start* with a `START` line, this will insert one.)
    - `gensub("^\n+|\n+$", "", "g")` replaces all leading and trailing newlines from the input record at hand and returns the result, to avoid any extra empty lines on output.

      - `gensub()` is a GNU-specific function that adds additional features to its POSIX-compliant sibling, `gsub()`, and, unlike `gsub()`, doesn't modify the input string in-place, but *returns* a *modified copy* instead.
  - `skipped=0` resets the flag that indicates that the previous record was a fully formed range.

Comment: thank you for the solution but it did not delete the lines. How do I know if I'm using GNU awk? I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and installed gawk.

Comment: The _default_ `awk` on Ubuntu is [Mawk](http://invisible-island.net/mawk/mawk.html), which will _not_ work. If you have Gawk installed, try invoking the command with `gawk` instead of `awk`. Run `awk -W v` to see what your `awk` is.

Comment: The output from awk -W -v: "GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.4, GNU MP 6.1.0)"

Comment: Using the very same Gawk version with your sample input yields your desired output for me. Is that not what you're getting? If you are getting the desired output, then your sample input data isn't representative of your problem, and you need to update it.

Comment: Here is the output using gawk:
START

text1
text2
text3
START

text4
END
text5
text6
START

test7
START

test8
END

Comment: Copy the input data _directly from your question as rendered in your browser, paste it into a *new* input file, and run the command against that. If you run `cat -A` on your current input file, does it show any unexpected control characters (anything starting with `^M`?).

Comment: I'm very sorry. The test file is in the ntfs drive.

Comment: If it's a *Windows*-originated file, you need to match Windows-style line endings: `\r\n` instead of just `\n`.

Comment: Thank very much for the solution! I'm also looking for the check mark :)

Answer (score -1):

```
 awk '{sub(/text4|END/,"")}/START/{c++;if(c==2)sub("START","")}length;/test7/{exit}' file

    START
    text1
    text2
    text3
    text5
    text6
    START
    test7
```

Comment: A solution based on hard-coded values that only work with the specific sample input is not helpful.