# Using sed in Linux to extract lines from a log file

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a log file which prints the following lines:

```
01:15:21.882 DEBUG [SampleProcess] 
Sample Message
01:15:21.882 DEBUG [SampleProcess1] 
Summary Report
Sample Text1: 126
Sample Text2: 2330
Sample Text3: 2331
Sample Text4: 0
01:15:21.883 DEBUG [SampleProcess2]
```

I was able to extract the Summary Report by using the below sed command

```
 sed -n '/Summary Report/,/Sample Text4/p' samplefile.log
```

However, I also want to print the timestamp when the Sample Report was generated.

So, currently with

```
sed -n '/Summary Report/,/Sample Text4/p' samplefile.log
```

I see the output as

```
Summary Report
    Sample Text1: 126
    Sample Text2: 2330
    Sample Text3: 2331
    Sample Text4: 0
```

I want the output as

```
01:15:21.882 DEBUG [SampleProcess1] 
    Summary Report
    Sample Text1: 126
    Sample Text2: 2330
    Sample Text3: 2331
    Sample Text4: 0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete only fully formed line ranges from a text file while ignoring those that only have a start delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294886/delete-only-fully-formed-line-ranges-from-a-text-file-while-ignoring-those-that)

Comment: from the duplicate, instead of deleting, use `-n` and `p` to print the matching lines.. similarly you can adapt the other answers presented in that q&a

Comment: Thanks. I am already using sed -n '/Summary Report/,/Sample Text4/p' samplefile.log to print the matching lines. I just need to also print one line before my first pattern match. Is that doable?

Comment: please go through the duplicate.. easiest to use is `tac+sed+tac`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^..:..:..\./{N;/Summary Report/!D;:a;N;/Sample Text4/!ba;s/\n/&    /gp}' file
```

Switch off automatic printing. If the current line is a timestamp and the next is not a `Summary Report`, delete the first line and repeat. Otherwise, gather up the following lines until the `Sample Text4`, indent all but the first line, print and repeat.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
sed -n '/Process1/{:a;N;/^\n/s/^\n//;/Sample Text/{p;s/.*//;};ba};' samplefile.log
```

Check out this link: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47942/how-to-get-all-lines-between-first-and-last-occurrences-of-patterns

Comment: This is GNU sed only.

Answer (score 0):

sed is for doing s/old/new **that is all**. For anything else you should be using awk:

```
$ awk '
    /DEBUG/ { prt() }
    { rec = rec $0 ORS }
    END { prt() }
    function prt() {
        if (rec ~ /Summary Report/) {
            printf "%s", rec
        }
        rec = ""
    }
' file
01:15:21.882 DEBUG [SampleProcess1]
Summary Report
Sample Text1: 126
Sample Text2: 2330
Sample Text3: 2331
Sample Text4: 0
```

Build up a record of all lines since the last prt() call. Every time you see a DEBUG line or at the END of input, print the record if necessary.

That will work using any awk in any shell in any UNIX system.

Clear, simple, robust, efficient, portable, extensible, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `perl` to slurp the file:

```
$ perl -0777 -lnE 'while (/^(?=[\d.:]+[ \t]+DEBUG[^\n]*$)(.+?)(?=^[\d.:]+[ \t]+DEBUG|\z)/gms)
                 { $s=$1; 
                   say "$s" if $s =~ m/^Sample Text4/ms  }' file
01:15:21.882 DEBUG [SampleProcess1] 
Summary Report
Sample Text1: 126
Sample Text2: 2330
Sample Text3: 2331
Sample Text4: 0
```

This works with two forward lookaheads `^(?=[\d.:]+[ \t]+DEBUG[^\n]*$)` that separates the example into three blocks delimited by a line with `DEBUG` in it.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/6RhJBS/1/)

Once you have each block, you can test if a substring is inside that block with

```
m/^Sample Text4/ms
```

If the substring is found, print the block.

---

Here is a POSIX sed solution that involves reversing the file (with `tail -r`) looking for the two patterns in reverse then reassembling the file into original order:

```
$ tail -r file.log | sed -n '/^Sample Text4/,/DEBUG/p' | tail -r
```

(The addition of `-r` to `tail` is a [fairly recent](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=877) POSIX addition and may not be in your OS. It is in recent BSD and OS X releases.)

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/Sample Message/{getline;print}/^S/' file

01:15:21.882 DEBUG [SampleProcess1] 
Summary Report
Sample Text1: 126
Sample Text2: 2330
Sample Text3: 2331
Sample Text4: 0
```